# recalculating view with wrap_contant on runtime

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a view inside a listview that contains information from user that can be changed on runtime.
when I first start the listview everything is fine, but the layout doesn't recalculate it's height during runtime, not even when I call **notifyDataSetChanged()**. and as result some of the text is below the view edge and can't be seen.

my view xml:

```
<com.fgdvir.adapters.ExpandingLayout
    android:id="@+id/expanding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lLExtraInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lL1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvExpandedDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:text="----"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="5" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivContactIcon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/contacts" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivLocationIcon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/location" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivTimeIcon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/delay_other" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivRepeatIcon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/repeat" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivMenuIcon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/menu_blak" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.fgdvir.adapters.ExpandingLayout>
```

the tvExpandedDescription is the textview that contains the user data. if because of the data rows are added, the LinearLayout with all the ImageViews is pushed down and can't be seen.

what can I do?
thanks

Comment: You can remove that row view and draw it again, using notifyDataSetChanged two times. RecyclerViewAdapter would be better suited for your use case.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use RecyclerViewAdapter? . I don't know this one..